# $L \in RE/R$ such that $L^R \cup L \in R$

Tags: formal-languages, computability

> Prove/disprove: $\exists L \in RE/R$ such that $L^R \cup L \in R$

Where in my context, $R$ is the turing decidable, and $RE$ is the recursively enurmable. I tried to find such an $L$ but couldn't. What I know for sure is that I need a language in $RE/R$ such that $L \cup L^R = \Sigma^*$, or am I also wrong?

Comment: Is $L^R$ the set of all reversed words of $L$, or is this something else?

Comment: Yes. Reversed words of $L$

Comment: Do you use $/$ to denote set difference or right quotient?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this sounds like a homework question to me, I will give the answer as a series of hints. (You should make a serious effort to solve the question after each hint, instead of just reading them all in short succession.)

First: Such an $L$ exists and $L \cup L^R$ is not necessarily $\Sigma^*$.

> Try $L \cup L^R = \{a^nb^n\} \cup \{b^na^n\}$.

---

> For each $n$, $L$ should contain exactly one of the words $a^nb^n$, $b^na^n$. How can you do this so that $L$ is in $RE/R$?

And finally the solution:

> Let $K$ be any set in $RE/R$ and let $L = \{a^nb^n \mid n \in K\} \cup \{b^na^n \mid n \notin K\}$.